# Classic ASP language (monthname for chinese)

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

Have been struggling to find a solution for this.
I am looking for monthname to return the chinese version of January (or spanish etc.). At the moment it is returning english.

The site is installed on an english windows machine.

I have tried adding session.lcid as well as: <%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>
but I keep getting the english version of the month name (and to change each occurrence is a major code change). Also I need to try and keep the date format as per what I have as changing that might be an issue as well.

Can anyone recommend an answer? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the [`SetLocale`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5xf99h19%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) function and the [locale identifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318693.aspx) of the language.

Sample test vbs script

```dos
Option Explicit

Dim language, outputString

    For Each language In Array( "es-es", "en-us", "zh" )
        SetLocale language
        outputString = outputString & MonthName( 2 ) & vbCrLf
    Next 

    WScript.Echo outputString
```

Output

[image: Script output capture]

Comment: Apologies, this is for classic asp requirement.

Comment: @Elad it works for classic asp. Just use `Response.Write` instead of `WScript.Echo`. The key is here using `SetLocale`.

Comment: @Elad, The posted code is a sample of the usage of the functions to change the language in the `vbscript` engine, the same used by asp in `vbscript` pages, and to obtain the data you need, it works (of course, the `Wscript.Echo` does not). If your requirements are other, then read [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525091%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Works.  Thank you

Comment: I used it and it worked, thanks but there is one thing about the MonthName function, the result in English capitalize the first letter of the month while in the remaining languages it does not. I had to create a asp classic function to do that. I am not an expert on asp classic, I was just adjusting some old web app written in asp classic.

Comment: @ElBayames I can't be sure about the rules for each language, I know in English month names should be capitalized while in Spanish they should not. Maybe MonthName is generating the correct usage